# DataGridView doubleclick to open a form vs. column autosize

Tags: c#, datagridview, click, double

I have a read only DataGridView in a Winform set to `fullrowselect` and the `CellDoubleClick` event is used to bring up a form. This is working just fine, however the problem is that this kills the functionality for an auto-sizing column width by double clicking the column dividers in the header row. Trying to do the latter also bring up the form.

An alternative is to use the `CellContentDoubleClick` event, but the downside to that is that it will only work when you double click on actual content, not empty space in the row.

Any idea for a optimal solution?

Comment: Add the MouseDown event to identify that you clicked on the header row : set a flag. Then test the flag in the double-click event: if the mousedown occured on the header, do nothing.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. Now I'm handling right click in header columns (for my context menu), double click in the header separator (to autosize the column width), click in the header colums (for sorting) and double clicking in the rows below the header for bringing up my form.